# Why does Visual Studio 2015 not recognize my local variable in a debugging session?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In the image below I am debugging and I want to see the value assigned to the variable "blah".  The variable is shown in the watch window along with the services variable which has the same scope.  I can see the value of services but VS tells me blah is not in scope.  Why do I see this error?
I tried assigning blah to blah2 and it works however the Watch window continues to tell me blah and blah2 are out of scope.  I cleaned and rebuilt the solution.  I restarted VS. I deleted bin and obj folders from the artifacts directory.

[image: debugging]

Answer (score 0):

My bad this has been posted on connect as a bug:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1038150/visual-studio-2015-debugger-doesnt-recognize-a-variable

The issue is reported as fixed in VS Update 2.  I am using Update 2, clearly it is not fixed.